# Reading database information before a button is clicked

Tags: ios, mysql

I have a registration page that is linked to a SQL database. Is there anyway possible that as soon as the user is choosing a username, and the username has already been taken that I can notify the user that this specific username is no longer available without having the user have to click the registration button to find this information out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and function

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
   //read DB here
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextFieldDelegate method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
     //Check if given username is in the Database or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Once**

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    //** Filter your DB using searchStr
    NSLog(@"%@",searchStr);
    return YES;
}
```